# EpiServer CMS - get all changed properties

Tags: episerver

I have an EPIServer CMS. I have a staging instance and a production instance. I want to be able to edit properties/texts in the staging instance, and then in one operation migrate all the new values to production. What is the easiest way to do this?

I suppose I should do something like programatically enumerate all changed properties since a given timestamp and then save key/values to a file, and then update in production from the file. Os is there a better way built-in to achieve the same?

Comment: Are you asking about editing the actual properties e.g. changing the type, name or description, or the values of properties on pages?

Comment: I just want to migrate the values.

Comment: In that case you'll need to create a custom export/import job as Anders mentions. Luckily everything is versioned so you can chose only to export whatever's changed since a certain point in time.

Comment: Thank you! Versioning is at the page level, right? So I could traverse all pages and save a version before editing, then after editing compare all properties in the latest version of the page to the saved version, and then export the changes to a file?

Comment: Yes, every modification (e.g. modifying the description) to a page will create a new version of that page.

I'm not completely sure, but I think all you have to do is check the IsModified field on the property after the page has been saved. That should save you a few lines of code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not built in. If your stage db is a copy of production when you start you can export the pages from stage and include page types and then import them to production, but they will get new ids and you'd have to delete the originals. You would also lose all updates made to production during development. I think you're better of writing that xml exporter/importer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Episerver Mirroring](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-6-RC1/EPiServer-CMS-Mirroring-20/) will solve your problem. You can use mirroring to move content from staging to prod with the help of scheduled job or by running the job manually.